# how to update list item in list view in android

Tags: android, android-listview

i have list view ,in list view i try to display images in list view after that i want change size of image and update it to list view..is it possible to update images at run-time....
and how can get current view that dispay currently and can we modify it..??

this is class....

```
public class GalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private int numcolumn;
private int NoOfListItem;
GridView grid;
int ListItemHeight;
private String[] header;
SharedPreferences groupbyPref;
private SharedPreferences GalleryPref;
ScreenshotLibrary myScreenshotLibrary = null;

// arrylist which contain path of images from sdcard..
ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();
private TableLayout table_layout;
// layout parm of image
LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms;
public int fromback = 0;
ImageView img;
private LruCache<String, Bitmap> mMemoryCache;
private int size;
Cursor imagecursor;
int counter = 0;

// Constructor
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public GalleryAdapter(Context gallery, int NumOfListItem, String[] str) {

}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NoOfListItem;

}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return itemList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public void setnumcol(int i) {
    grid.setNumColumns(i);
    grid.requestLayout();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public int ListItemHeight(int length) {
    SharedPreferences ImageSizePref = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
    if (length % numcolumn == 0) {
        return ((length / numcolumn))
                * ImageSizePref.getInt("ImageParm", 100) + 55;
    } else {
        return ((length / numcolumn) + 1)
                * ImageSizePref.getInt("ImageParm", 100) + 55;
    }

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
    View customRow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    // textview which display header of screenshot library
    TextView txt = (TextView) customRow.findViewById(R.id.header);
    txt.setText(header[position]);
    // tablelayout which will be used to contain images inside that
    table_layout = (TableLayout) customRow.findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
    int count = 0;
    // loop for num of row in view

    for (int i = 0; i < RowMaking(numcolumn); i++) {
        //
        TableRow row = new TableRow(mContext);
        row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        // inner loop used for number of images in each row of
        // tablelayout....and num of
        for (int j = 1; j <= numcolumn; j++) {
            img = new ImageView(mContext);
            img.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            if (count < itemList.size()) {
                int resId = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(
                        itemList.get(count++), "drawable",
                        mContext.getPackageName());
                loadBitmap(resId, img);
                // img.setLayoutParams(parms);
                img.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(size, size));
                Log.i("fromcache", "num" + counter);
                img.getResources();

            } else {
                break;
            }
            row.addView(img);

        }

        table_layout.addView(row);

    }
    customRow.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(
            ListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ListItemHeight(itemList
                    .size())));

    return customRow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can update listview with dynamicdata..

just see this tutorial...

http://www.developerfusion.com/article/145373/android-listviews-with-dynamic-data/

and i reccomend you to use piccaso for images...

Use picasso which is easy to use..

In your Adapter ..

```
    @Override
    public void getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     ImageView view = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ranking_prod_pic);

     Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(view); //url is image url

     //you can resize image if you want

     /* Picasso.with(context) .load(url) .resize(50, 50) .centerCrop() .into(view) */

    }
```

http://square.github.io/picasso/